# ImportError: cannot import name 'main' when installing from requirements.txt

Tags: python

I am getting runpy.py file error while install packge. Kindly help me anyone.

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: Which OS? [Seems ubuntu/debian had an issue with pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221). You should probably reinstall `pip`.